# Consolidate Perforce `add` and `edit` file operations

Tags: automation, perforce, staging

To automate Perforce staging, I face a dilemma that `add` and `edit` are two different ops and they work on files of different SCM status, i.e., "already under SCM or not".

This is different from git where staging is uniformly `add`.

I'd like to have something like pseudo-code:

```
filepath = '/path/to/myfile.ext'
if p4.is_under_scm(filepath):
    p4.edit(filepath)
else:
    p4.add(filepath)
```

or better yet, simply hide the detail with:

```
p4.staging(filepath)
```

How should I achieve this with calling `p4` command-line program?. I'm not using any programming-language bindings right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the `p4 reconcile` command, which automatically opens workspace files for an action that matches their current state relative to the depot.

Keep in mind if you go this route that `reconcile` operates only on *unopened* files that are *different* from the depot version, so it's meant to be used *after* making local modifications (this is different from the standard workflow where you open a file with `p4 edit` prior to editing it -- the idea is that you use `reconcile` to fix things after the fact if you've had to work disconnected or something like that).  In addition, if you change your mind about what you're doing with the file (e.g. you delete the local copy after it's been opened for `edit` but before you `submit`), you may need to `revert -k` it and re-`reconcile` to ensure that it's open for the correct action.

For something that matches the pseudocode in your question, you probably want the `p4 have` command, which tells you if a local file corresponds to a depot revision (and if so which one).  `p4 edit` only works on a file that you `have`, whereas `p4 add` would be for a file in your workspace that does not correspond to an existing depot file.  (A very subtle point here -- it's possible for the file to *map to* a depot file despite not having been synced from the depot!  If that's the case you'll hit a conflict when you go to submit your `add`.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. I did try using reconcile before edits and found nothing opened for add/edit. It all makes sense now. This difference adds to the work of making cross-SCM abstractions! I wish there was a grand tutorial on the Perforce clone of git workflow for returning Perforce users like me (last used over 10 years ago and exclusively p4v/p4win, no p4 CLI experience).

Comment: Git and Perforce workflows don't exactly have a 1:1 mapping, but the reconcile command gets you most of the way there if you think of `p4 reconcile` + `p4 submit` being the same as `git commit -a`.